# GameMaker (RPG) Room transition problem how to save the progress made?

Tags: game-maker

My problem is that I made 2 levels and made 2 doors and since I want to go from room1 to room2 so I wrote this code in the door:

```
new_room = rm_number2;
new_x = 96;
new_y = 32;
```

and this code in the player:

```
/// Go through the door
if (room_exists(other.new_room)) {
    room_goto(other.new_room);
    x = other. new_x;
    y = other. new_y;
}
```

but my problem is that when I kill the enemy and go through the door to room2 and go back they respawn. The room is persistent. But since every time the player goes through the door the door makes a new room1 (or at least that is what I think the problem is) the game doesn't keep room1 as it was before going through the door.

Answer (score -1):

NVM ppl i found the way its by triggering a save .ini every time i use the door 
and load it and over write it not in that order but u get it

Comment: or keep your level object alive all the time, say in a list. (but don't keep too many levels alive at once)